# Catching order changing events in Shopware 5.4.*

Tags: shopware, shopware5

in Shopware 5.4, I was able to catch the events of changing:

- order status
- payment status

But I need to catch the events of:

- changing order items like replace, remove or add
- change in shipping and/or billing address
- change in payment info like payment gateway, etc.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @toesslab No so far

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code which worked for order status and payment status? Was it inside a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to add an `Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber`:
With the Symfony DI tag `doctrine.event_subscriber`.

This will solve all changes via backend or api, cause they are doctrine based.
Changes without doctrine are hardly trackable.

```php
<?php

namespace <your namespace>;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Shopware\Models\Order\Detail;

class Doctrine implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::preRemove,
            Events::postUpdate
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if($args->getEntity() instanceof Detail)
        {
            // order detail has removed
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs  $eventArgs
     */
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $enity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if ($enity instanceof Detail) {
            // order detail has changed
        }
    }

}
```